# tikzpicture draw inside node/frame

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce a picture and I'm having a problem (since this is my very first experience with tikzpictures). The picture is the following: [image: image to be reproduced]

My problem is of how to create the part that is inside the frame in the middle and more precisely how am I supposed to "frame" it like that (with the underlying part - description) and connect it later with the other nodes I have.

Sorry if the question is very naive. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `fit` and `calc` libraries. The `\pgflinewidth/2` is used to fix the width of the lower rectangle.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ellipse,label=270:C++,align=left,draw] (a) at (0,0) {Simulation\\ Objects};
\node[ellipse,label=270:OT cl,align=left,draw] (b) at (4,0) {Simulation\\ Objects};
\draw[latex-latex] (a) -- (b);
\node (c) at ($(a.south west)+(-1,-1)$) {};
\node (d) at ($(b.north east)+(1,1)$) {};
\node[fit=(c)(d),draw] (e) {};
\draw ($(e.south west)+(\pgflinewidth/2,0)$) rectangle node {NS2 Shell Executable Command (ns)} ($(e.south east)+(-\pgflinewidth/2,-0.7)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason the text in the lower rectangle is out of place for me as shown in the following [picture](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2575962/Selection_002.png)

Also when I'm trying to add the node from the left (using `\node (tclscript) [left of=e] {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{images/FileScript}} node at +(0,1.00) {\footnotesize\sc Tcl Simulation Script};`) I get the following [result](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2575962/Selection_003.png)

Comment: Try `left=of e.west` for the second issue. Which version of `TikZ` are you using?

Comment: `Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`

When I'm putting the '=' before of it gives me an error. Also when I have the '=' after of and write e.west it gives me an error. Should this be of the version I'm using?

Comment: OK, for the second one I also has to use the `positioning` library. The first problem still holds though.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the first problem as well. Apparently the problem was caused by the arguments I was using in the tikzpicture : `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, auto]`. Thanks again for your help!